# Replacing dynamic number of tags in string with dynamic values of String - Java

Tags: java, replace

I have two String in Java.

```
**String str1 = "Dear Candidate **<Name>**, Your installment of home loan of a/c **<Loan A/c No.>** is due for Amount of Rs. **<Installment Amount>**. Please paid this installment before this due date **<Due Date>**.";

String str2 = "<Name>Deepraj <Loan A/c No.>301201 <Installment Amount>25000 <Due Date>20-Arpil-2014";**
```

I want to replace all String str1 angular brackets data like **""** with the information of String str2 "Deepraj"...etc.

```
"<Name>" replaced with "Deepraj"
"<Loan A/c No.>" replaced with "301201"
"<Installment Amount>" replaced with "25000"
"<Due Date>" replaced with "20-April-2014"
```

If there is any number of angular brackets data comes in str1 or str2 can replaced dynamically.

Please any one help me to get output of this by dynamic or static form.

Thanks

Comment: I would create a map from the values in the second string (key: the text in brackets, value: the text to replace). After that either using a simple parser (iterating through the text in str1 and handling state) or using regexes, I would create the new text.

Comment: Please provide me a code how it performed.
Mr.Bakos whatever you said in your reply please show me in code.

Comment: I guess in this place the question should contain the code first. ;-) These kind of problems (the easy ones without attempts to be solved) are usually homeworks and are advised to be marked like that if that is the case. I would not like to ruin the journey to solve the problem with complete code. Just to be sure I am not misleading: The Strings in Java are immutable, you have to create a new String (probably with StringBuilder), you cannot/should not replace characters within the same String object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for the above question:

```
public static String replaceTagData() {
    String str = "Dear Candidate **<Name>**, Your installment of home loan of a/c **<Loan A/c No.>** is due for Amount of Rs. **<Installment Amount>**. Please paid this installment before this due date **<Due Date>**.";

    if(str.length() > 1) {
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Name", "Test");
        map.put("Loan_Acc", "0987654321");
        map.put("Installment_Amount", "25000");
        map.put("Due_Date", "12-03-2021");

        if(map != null && map.size()>0) {
            str = str.replace("<Name>", map.get("Name")).replace("<Loan A/c No.>", map.get("Loan_Acc")).replace("<Installment Amount>", map.get("Installment_Amount")).replace("<Due Date>", map.get("Due_Date"));
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @fps, removed the junk line, now it is compiling. Please vote and accept the answer.